# Fedora 16 ssh over the internet/home network. Same computer ok

Tags: ssh, fedora, hostname

I think I have set up the ssh servers on my home machine, but I don't know how to ssh into it from a client computer on the same network, let alone over the internet.

From the same server, I can do: `ssh user@server`

It has a static ip 192.168.1.100 which I have added to /etc/hosts, and everything is fine.

If I do so from the client in the same network, I can `ping host`, but I can't ssh. It just stays stuck when I type `ssh server`.

Also, how would I connect over the internet? I have a "name@dyndns.org" setup for the dynamic IP, but I wouldn't know how to ssh into that and then have it be routed to the 192.168.1.100 computer.

The things I researched are already written (starting sshd service, editing /etc/hosts, pinging). I haven't been able to find any further info on google, as I'm not sure what I need to look for.

This is the output from client of `ssh -vvv server`.

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

Comment: @Gilles I think I need to add a key to my server from looking at the output of ssh -vvv host.  The output is quite long from the host machine.  Let me see if I'll head in the right direction by trying to add a key.

Comment: @Gilles I pasted the output from the client machine.  I'm still trying to see how to add the keys to the server machine (if that is indeed my problem).  Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be the full output. ssh still needs to try the password based auth. Please paste the complete output till you see the prompt.

Comment: @AdityaPatawari Hi Aditya, that is the full output.  It hangs there.  I need to Ctrl-C out of it.  I'm thinking it may be a permission problem, but it doesn't seem like that right now.  Any directions to look into will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: check out /var/log/secure. there must be something in there.

Comment: @AdityaPatawari I've been trying to play with the configs, but nothing seems to solve the problem.  I'm using VMWare for the client if that may be the problem.  /var/log/secure says did not receive identification string from client_ip (192.168.**.**)

Comment: @Gilles I put the authorized_keys in the server ~/.ssh folder, but it's still not connecting.  I can connect to another ssh server from client, so I'm a bit confused as it seems the server says identification not received.  I have also been playing with sshd_config server side but not working.  Thanks all.

Comment: @chemelnucfin: I am stumped here. tell me the permission of your .ssh directory.

Comment: @AdityaPatawari server ls -al from ~/.ssh returns:  I have seen mentions of both 644 600 and 744 700 for the files/directories, but not sure which permissions for the last 2.
drwx------ .
drwx------ ..
-rw------- authorized_keys
-rw------- id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- known_hosts

Comment: I want to know the permission for .ssh. In your home directory do a `ls -al|grep .ssh` and paste the output.

Comment: @AdityaPatawari Hi Aditya, it says drwx------. 2 user user 4096 Dec 31 17:32 .ssh

Answer (score 1):

Just try telnet to port 22 on the other host, if you are seeing OpenSSH server header then as such there is no problem with the server listening or client able to reach the opensshd server, but could be problem with ssh_config. If you are not able to telnet to port 22, then opensshd server is not reachable on the network. Possible reasons, network configuration, firewall rejections.

Comment: your `ssh -vvv` shows that sshd server is listening but the client is unable to establish the connection. Check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora has a firewall enabled by default which block all ports.  You just need to open up TCP Port 22 for OpenSSH in order to allow access from other computers.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Basic_Fedora_Linux_Firewall_Configuration